# how can one querying sap s4 hana tables data from sap hana studio or third party tool

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, s4hana

How do one can access/query SAP S/4HANA table data through E.g. `select * from kn01 where client=100`:

1. SAP HANA STUDIO
2. OBDC driver
3. Oracle SQL developer

Secondly I have a system access through HANA studio , but I can't see any application tables over there. It seems I'm just querying data from metadata database. What exactly info I need to get connected to SAP application data like purchase orders, GL data, sales orders , invoices, customer, etc.

regards
Anwer

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA STUDIO ->
Open Sql console

[image]